# Pandas First Value That Doesnt Return KeyError

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, keyerror

I have a dataframe that has *either* column `A` or `B`

I was hoping for a syntax that uses the `or` operator to have a stntax like:

```
Value = df.at['Total','A'] or df.at['Total','B']
```

but I still receive a `KeyError` exception. Is there a shorthand way to achieve this instead of doing something like:

```
if 'A' in df.columns:
    Value = df.at['Total','A']
else:
    Value = df.at['Total','B']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use ternary conditional operator:

```py
df.at["Total", "B" if "B" in df else "A"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have an inconsistent format, why not make it consistent? [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) your columns to have a unique name:

```
df.rename(columns={'B': 'A'}).at['Total', 'A']
```

This is handy to generalize to multiple aliases:

```
aliases = ['B', 'C', 'D']
df.rename(columns=dict.fromkeys(aliases, 'A')).at['Total', 'A']
```

##### further generalization

Alternatively, using an index [`intersection`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.intersection.html), which also enables you to pass an arbitrary number of aliases:

```
df.at['Total', next(iter(df.columns.intersection(['A', 'B'])))]
```

Note that **in case of multiple matches** (e.g if you have both A and B) this gives you the first match in order of the DataFrame's columns. If you want the first match in a custom order:

```
# first try to match B, then A
aliases = ['B', 'A']
df.at['Total', next(iter(pd.Index(aliases).intersection(df.columns)))]
```

Answer (score 0):

If your pandas dataframe will always have the same number of columns in the same order, you could use the column index instead of the name. For example, to grab the whole first column:

```
df[[1]]
```

Or to grab the column entry in the first row:

```
df.iloc[0, 1]
```

Comment: The number of columns will be different so unfortunately this will not work. I have to go based on column name